# Asp.net mvc3 localization - linking resource with view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, localization

I use the localization paradigm of one resx file per view in all my projects. I have two identical folder structures for Resources and Views and I link the resource and the view like so:

```
@using Res = [Namespace].Resources.[Controller].[View]
<p>@Res.[ResourceKey]</p>
```

Is it possible to get asp.net to use/link the resource file without the using statements and defining a `Custom Tool Namespace` for all my Resx files? (Yes, I am **that** lazy.)

Answer (score 1):

Open your `web.config` in your Views folder.

[image]

Add the namespace for your resources.

[image]

Restart VS as it doesn't pick up the namespace so it's not showing intellisense.

Call your resources from any view without adding `using` statements inside your `*.cshtml` files.

Comment: Looks interesting! I tried to add it but wound up with questions; would I have to add this for all my view folders? Currently I use /Views/[Controllername]/[Viewname].cshtml and /Resources/[Controllername]/[Viewname].resx, would I have to refactor it? Wouldn't that also mean that I have all my resources in available in all views? This is something I can't do as my resource keys overlap a lot; for example many views contain a different meaning for a "TabInfo" key. I have at least 10 different "Index.cshtml" views and "Index.resx" resource files, would that not cause a collision?

Comment: So you basically you have a structure by convention (for every Views folder a Resources folder in it), am i correct? There will be no collision because you would use different namespace for a different view. So lets say you have a View called UserLogin.cshtml, and a Resources file UserLogin.resx. Then you would call it UserLogin.[Key]. It really depends how big is your application. I personally use using statements, as it's cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: Sorry I don't. I have a Views folder and a separate Resources folder. I'm trying http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181738/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC3-Application-Part but I added the `@using`  that I have. If I did use the folder structure you mentioned and had `<add namespace="[Project].Views.ViewFolder1.Resources"/><add namespace="[Project].Views.ViewFolder2.Resources"/>` What if both Resource folders had "Edit.resx"? This http://stackoverflow.com/a/5510110/694325 is very similar to mine but I want a more dynamic solution :)