# Internationalization Compilation Error fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, internationalization, globalization

I am following the answer below to make globalization happen.
[Globalization in ASP.Net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509965/globalization-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

However, I have failed.

I am getting back a compilation fail error for the following line:

```
using ViewResources;
```

I have created Resources folder, created 2 resource file per locale(ViewResources.resx, ViewResources.en.resx), added

```
<add namespace="ViewResources" />
```

to web.config in Views folder and it fails like a boss. 
`Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ViewResources' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: "pleaze gimme teh codez." Are you serious?

Comment: did you downvote? @meagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the file type as 'embedded resource', to do this select the file in solution explorer, right click-> select properties, change build action to 'embedded resource'

Comment: ahhh it worked. canyou also add to your answer that I need to `Copy to output directory` as `always`

Comment: Already captured in your comment, don't forget to mark as answer :-)